# Error: Non-nullable variable 'newTaskTitle' must be assigned before it can be used

Tags: flutter, dart

tasks_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todoey_app/widgets/tasks_list.dart';
import 'package:todoey_app/screens/add_task_screen.dart';
import 'package:todoey_app/models/task.dart';

class TasksScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TasksScreen> createState() => _TasksScreenState();
}

class _TasksScreenState extends State<TasksScreen> {
  List<Task> tasks = [
    Task(name: 'Buy milk'),
    Task(name: 'Buy eggs'),
    Task(name: 'Buy bread'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AddTaskScreen(
              (newTaskTitle) {
                // print(newTaskTitle);
                setState(() {
                  tasks.add(Task(name: newTaskTitle));
                });
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 60.0, left: 30.0, right: 30.0, bottom: 30.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.list,
                    size: 30.0,
                    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  radius: 30.0,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Todoey',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 50.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  '${tasks.length} Tasks',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                  )),
              child: TasksList(tasks),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

add_task_screen.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function addTaskCallback;

  AddTaskScreen(this.addTaskCallback);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // String? newTaskTitle;
    // String newTaskTitle = '';
    String newTaskTitle = "It's Working";
    // String newTaskTitle;

    return Container(
      color: Color(0xff757575),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
            )),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Add Task',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                fontSize: 30.0,
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              onChanged: (newText) {
                // print(newText);
                newTaskTitle = newText;
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(newTaskTitle);
                addTaskCallback(newTaskTitle);
              },
              child: Text(
                'Add',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have initialized newTaskTitle but when i type new text in my TextField and try to add it to my Task list but instead of taking the new value that's comming from textField it only takes the value that I have initialized at the beginning which is newTaskTitle = "It's Working";.

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ValueSetter for this.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  //final Function addTaskCallback;
  final ValueSetter<String> onChanged; //THIS LINE

  AddTaskScreen(this.onChanged);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // String? newTaskTitle;
    // String newTaskTitle = '';
    String newTaskTitle = "It's Working";
    // String newTaskTitle;

    return Container(
      color: Color(0xff757575),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
            )),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Add Task',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                fontSize: 30.0,
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              onChanged: (newText) {
                // print(newText);
                newTaskTitle = newText;
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(newTaskTitle);
                onChanged(newTaskTitle); //THIS LINE
              },
              child: Text(
                'Add',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```